# RTK Query how to not run transformResponse if cached data is used

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I am running RTKQ with `transformResponse` on a set of data that is not that time senstive and doesn't change often. That is, I only need to refresh it few times, or even just once in the entire app.

Let's say, I set `createApi{ keepUnusedDataFor: 60*60*12, ... //12 hrs`.

However, every time when the data is used, `transformResponse` will run the unnecessary transform loops on the same old cache data anyway:

```
transformResponse: response => response.data.map(item=> ... //data looping & transforming
```

My question is, since my cache data did not re-fetch and did not change, is there a way to tell the `transformResponse` not to run it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see in the source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/b71f5bb12f26b60dc397f85b78ee6031bce46bbc/packages/toolkit/src/query/core/buildThunks.ts#L293), `transformResponse` only runs directly after a request was made and the response was received from the server. There must be something wrong going on in your application.

Comment: Thank you. I went back to check the code. I can confirm that you are correct.